# 複数行のText（UITextViewを活用して作成したTextFieldに入力されたText ）をFirestoreに格納したい

Tags: firebase, swiftui

UITextViewを活用してTextFieldを作成したのですが、
そこに書かれたTextをFirestoreに格納したいです。

通常のやり方だと、格納されません。
どうしたら良いでしょうか、すいませんがご教示ください。

```
//作成した複数行のTextField
struct MultiLineTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        MultiLineTextField.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        textView.isEditable = true
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.text = "xxx"
        textView.textColor = UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.4, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1) : .lightGray
        textView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        textView.backgroundColor = UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1) : UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1)
        return textView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent : MultiLineTextField

        init(parent1: MultiLineTextField) {
            parent = parent1
        }

        func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            if self.parent.text == "" {
                textView.text = ""
                textView.textColor = .black
            }
        }

        internal func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            if self.parent.text == "" {
                textView.text = "xxx"
                textView.textColor = UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? .darkGray : .lightGray
            }
        }
    }
}

//firestoreへの格納時の処理、textがMultiLineTextFieldで取得した値
db.collection("xxx").document("xxx").setData([..., "text": self.text,...]){(error) in
        if error != nil{
            print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 「格納されません」とありますが、どのような結果になるのでしょうか? 実行時エラーになるとか(その場合はエラー内容も)、エラーにはならないが期待した結果にならない(その場合は実際の結果も)を教えていただけませんか。ちなみにエラー情報をデバッグ用に`print`で出力する場合には、`localizedDescription`を使うよりも`print(error!)`とかの方が、より多くの情報が出力されます。

Answer (score 0):

> nekketsuuuさん
> user40929と同じ人で、別アカウントの者です。
> user40929としてログイン出来ず、こちらからの返答となりすいません。(また信用度が低いため、コメント追加できないためこちらに書かせていただきます)
> 状況としては、Firestoreへの追加処理をすると、エラーは起きないのですが、追加する予定のFirestoreの対象フィールドにはなにも値が追加されていませんでした。(フィールド自体はできました)

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: アカウントを二重に作成してしまった場合のことについては、こちら「[間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)を参照されると良いでしょう。「コメント」と「回答」の使い分けについては既にご理解いただいているようですが、コメントが付けられる質問については、正しく使い分けるようにお願いします。

Comment: Chiaki Obayashi さんはこの投稿に使用したアカウントを含め、都合3つのアカウントを作成してしまっている状態だと思われます。[その1](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/40929), [その2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/39869) / OOPer さんの提示したヘルプページを参考にアカウントのマージを行ってください。